# Take element inside url

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I will know how to take this element(value of language : en, fr) inside

rewriting url :
http://localhost/test/boutique/index.php/language/fr

normal url
http://localhost/test/boutique/index.php?language=fr

Normal url works fine and I can change my language 
in rewriting it does'nt work $_GET['language'] is on null

Maybe I must write in htaccess, if yes what is the code
Tk

my code :

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['language']) || isset($_GET['language'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['language']) && !empty($_GET['language']) && $OSCOM_Language->exists($_GET['language'])) {
      $OSCOM_Language->set($_GET['language']);
    }

    $_SESSION['language'] = $OSCOM_Language->get('code');
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Take EN or FR

Comment: Take them where? On a date? It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard. I need to know if I am in En or FR for example. For that in my url you en or fr. In rewriting mode $_GET['language'] does'nt work.  in normal URL, I have no problem

Answer (score 0):

One solution you could use be would to use your .htaccess file

`RewriteRule ^test/boutique/index/(.*)$ /test/boutique/index.php?language=$1[NC,L,QSA]`

This would solve your problem.  You're telling the URL to look for the one given, and then translate it in to where to go.

All of your `(.*)` become "variables" defined by their position in the string.  $1, $2, $3, etc etc etc.....